# Chaining function for range-based for loop

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, iterator, c++14

**Motivation:** I'm relatively new to C++. I'm writing a function meant to be used with range-based for loops. The goal is to be able to iterate over multiple containers at once, each in turn (essentially Python's `itertools.chain`), with as littler overhead as possible (e.g. no copying containers).

**Usage:**

```
vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
vector<int> b = {5, 6, 7, 8};
list<int> c = {9, 9, 4};
for (auto& i : chain_it(a, b, a, b, c)) { 
    cout << i << " "; 
}
```

This should print out:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 4
> ```

**Implementation**:

Working example also available at [ideone](https://ideone.com/kFMo9m).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct ref_or_copy
{
    ref_or_copy(T&& rval) 
        : storage(new T(std::move(rval)))
        , val(*storage) { }
    ref_or_copy(T& lval) : val(lval) { }

    std::unique_ptr<T> storage;
    T& val;
};

template <typename C1, typename C2>
struct chain_obj_struct {
  ref_or_copy<std::remove_reference_t<C1>> c1;
  ref_or_copy<std::remove_reference_t<C2>> c2;
  struct iterator {
    decltype(std::begin(c1.val)) it1;
    decltype(std::begin(c1.val)) it1_end;
    decltype(std::begin(c2.val)) it2;
    bool in_first;

    iterator& operator++() {
      if (in_first) {
        ++it1;
        if (it1 == it1_end) {
          in_first = false;
        }
      } else { 
        ++it2;
      }
      return *this;
    }

    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*it1)>>::value,
        decltype(*it1), decltype(*it2)>::type
    operator*() 
    {
      if (in_first) return *it1;
      return *it2;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator& i2) { 
      if (in_first != i2.in_first) return false;
      if (in_first)
        return it1 == i2.it1;
      else
        return it2 == i2.it2;
    }
    bool operator!=(const iterator& i2) {
        return !this->operator==(i2);
    }
  };

  iterator begin() {
    return iterator{std::begin(c1.val), std::end(c1.val), std::begin(c2.val), true};
  }

  iterator end() {
    return iterator{std::end(c1.val), std::end(c1.val), std::end(c2.val), false};
  }
};

template <typename C1, typename C2>
chain_obj_struct<C1, C2> chain_obj(C1&& c1, C2&& c2) {
    return chain_obj_struct<C1, C2>{std::forward<C1>(c1), std::forward<C2>(c2)};
}

template <typename C>
auto chain_it(C&& c) { return std::forward<C>(c); }

template <typename C1, typename C2, typename... Cs>
auto chain_it(C1&& c1, C2&& c2)
{
    return chain_obj(std::forward<C1>(c1), std::forward<C2>(c2));
}

template <typename C1, typename... Cs>
auto chain_it(C1&& c1, Cs&&... cs)
{
    return chain_obj(std::forward<C1>(c1), chain_it(std::forward<Cs>(cs)...));
}
```

**Explanation**:

`chain_obj_struct` is a basic container which implements just what is needed for the range-based for loop to work. It implements `begin()` and `end()` which return the iterators that end up iterating across both ranges.

Most of the logic is in `chain_obj_struct::iterator` which implements preincrement, unary `*`, and equality/inequality. This code is pretty straightforward, except for the return type of unary `*`, which picks the more consty return type.

`chain_obj` is the helper function to create `chain_obj_struct`s without having to specify types.

I ran into a difficulty when chaining chain objects, that is, when trying something like this:

```
for (auto& i : chain_obj(a, chain_obj(b, a)) { ... }
```

Initially `chain_obj` just took references of its parameters. It appeared that the temporary `chain_obj_struct` returned by `chain_obj(b, a)` would get destructed and the code would segfault. However, I absolutely did *not* want to make a copy of the container being iterated over until absolutely necessary. But I wasn't sure how to take a reference if I could, but copy the object if I had to.

My solution was the `ref_or_copy` helper struct which keeps a reference if it can (`ref_or_copy(T& lval)` constructor) or stores a local copy if it must (`ref_or_copy(T&& rval)` constructor). With the former constructor the only overhead is for a null `std::unique_ptr`. `chain_obj_struct` thus keeps `ref_or_copy`s around which do the best they can.

The rest is just the `chain_it` variadic template implementation which does perfect forwarding as necessary.

**Questions**:

- Was the `ref_or_copy` a good/necessary approach (i.e. is there a better way to do that)?
- Does this code follow best practices in general?
- Any other comments in particular?

Comment: Have a look at `view::concat` in [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library

Comment: Heh, I [asked a question about this too](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/105117/31292).

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the top.

**`ref_or_copy`**

Firstly, it's an odd name, since we're never copying. We're either referring or moving. But secondly, it's bigger than it needs to be, and incurs allocation overhead. We can hugely simplify this changing:

```
template <typename T>
struct ref_or_copy
{ ... };

ref_or_copy<std::remove_reference_t<C1>> c1;
ref_or_copy<std::remove_reference_t<C2>> c2;
```

into:

```
C1 c1;
C2 c2;
```

Wait what? Consider the usage like:

```
template <typename T>
T wrapped(T&& val) { return T{std::forward<T>(val)}; }
```

In the lvalue case, `T` will be some type `U&`, so we're referring to the passed in `val`. In the rvalue case, `T` will be some type `V`, so we'll be move-constructed from `val`. Everything checks out.

**What about non-member begin?**

This is definitely the Forgot About Dre of C++11 container programming:

```
struct Foo {
    int arr[2]{10, 11};
};

int* begin(Foo& f) { return f.arr; }
int* end(Foo& f) { return f.arr + 2; }

Foo d;
for (auto i : chain_it(d, d)) { // error: no matching function call to 'begin'
}
```

Where you use `std::begin` and `std::end`, you'll have to make unqualified calls with the `std::` functions in scope in order to do the right thing.

**Chain of one**

If try to do:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
for (int& i : chain_it(a)) { ++i; }
```

I would be quite surprised when `a[0]` was still `1` at the end. I'd also be surprised that this doesn't compile:

```
int d[] = {10, 11};
for (int& i : chain_it(d)) { ... }
```

Since the last container always gets `chain_it()`-ed as one, this is a serious issue. Both have the same root cause. The overload of `chain_it` that takes a single argument has the wrong return type:

```
template <typename C>
auto chain_it(C&& c) { return std::forward<C>(c); }
```

For the `vector`, we're *copying* it. And for the array, we're decaying it and ending up with a pointer. We want to return an lvalue reference for lvalue references, and a value for rvalue references. That is, trivially:

```
template <typename C>
C chain_it(C&& c) { return std::forward<C>(c); }
```