# Chain multiple containers

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

Python has [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), but C++ has nothing. This is my attempt to implement such a thing. Looking mainly for comments about potentially smarter ways of doing things or potential pitfalls this code falls into based on its current implementation.

Currently, the objects that `chain()` will give back will be a reference if all the corresponding containers dereference to the same type, otherwise it will be a value (e.g. chaining a `vector<int>` and `deque<int>` will give an `int&`, but if the second was a `deque<long>` instead would give an `int`).

First, some metaprogramming boilerplate:

```
namespace adl_details {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    template <typename C>
    auto adl_begin(C&& c) {
        return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
    }

    template <typename C>
    auto adl_end(C&& c) {
        return end(std::forward<C>(c));
    }    
}

using adl_details::adl_begin;
using adl_details::adl_end;

template <typename C>
using iter_t = decltype(adl_begin(std::declval<C>()));

template <typename C>
using iter_pair_t = std::pair<iter_t<C>, iter_t<C>>;

template <typename C>
using deref_t = decltype(*std::declval<iter_t<C>>());

template <typename T>
struct type_is { using type = T; };

template <typename... T>
struct nondecay_common_type;

template <typename... T>
using nondecay_common_type_t = typename nondecay_common_type<T...>::type;

template <typename T>
struct nondecay_common_type<T> : type_is<T> { };

template <typename T>
T makeT();

template <typename T, typename... U>
struct nondecay_common_type<T, U...>
: type_is<decltype(true ? makeT<T>() : std::declval<nondecay_common_type_t<U...>>())>
{ };
```

(`nondecay_common_type` is necessary because `std::common_type_t<int&, int&>` yields `int` but I want it to yield `int&`. `makeT` is necessary because if I use `std::declval`, `std::common_type_t<int, int>` would yield `int&&` but I want it to yield `int`).

And now the main event:

```
template <typename... Containers>
class Chainer {
    using sequence = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Containers)>;
    using deref_type = nondecay_common_type_t<deref_t<Containers>...>;

public:
    Chainer(Containers&&... c)
    : containers(std::forward<Containers>(c)...)
    { }

    class iterator 
    {
    public:
        iterator(iter_pair_t<Containers>... pairs)
        : iter_pairs(pairs...)
        { }

        deref_type operator*() {
            return dereference(sequence{});
        }

        iterator& operator++() {
            increment(sequence{});
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator++(int ) {
            iterator tmp(*this);
            ++*this;
            return tmp;
        }

        bool operator==(iterator const& rhs) {
            return iter_pairs == rhs.iter_pairs;
        }

        bool operator!=(iterator const& rhs) {
            return iter_pairs != rhs.iter_pairs;
        }        

    private:
        void increment(std::index_sequence<> ) {
        }

        template <size_t I, size_t... Is>
        void increment(std::index_sequence<I, Is...> ) {
            auto& cur_pair = std::get<I>(iter_pairs);
            if (cur_pair.first != cur_pair.second) {
                ++cur_pair.first;
            }
            else {
                increment(std::index_sequence<Is...>{});
            }
        }

        template <size_t I>
        deref_type dereference(std::index_sequence<I> ) {
            return *std::get<I>(iter_pairs).first;
        }

        template <size_t I, size_t... Is>
        deref_type dereference(std::index_sequence<I, Is...> ) {
            auto& cur_pair = std::get<I>(iter_pairs);
            if (cur_pair.first != cur_pair.second) {
                return *cur_pair.first;
            }
            else {
                return dereference(std::index_sequence<Is...>{});
            }
        }

        std::tuple<iter_pair_t<Containers>...> iter_pairs;
    };

    iterator begin() { return begin_impl(sequence{}); }
    iterator end() { return end_impl(sequence{}); }

private:
    template <size_t... Is>
    iterator begin_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
        return iterator{std::make_pair(adl_begin(std::get<Is>(containers)),
                                       adl_end(std::get<Is>(containers)))...};
    }

    template <size_t... Is>
    iterator end_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
        return iterator{std::make_pair(adl_end(std::get<Is>(containers)),
                                       adl_end(std::get<Is>(containers)))...};
    }    

    std::tuple<Containers...> containers;
};
```

Examples:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    std::deque<int> d{4, 5, 6};

    for (int& i : chain(v, d)) {
        ++i;
    }

    for (int j : chain(std::vector<int>{1, 2}, std::deque<int>{3, 4, 5}, std::list<int>{6, 7})) {
        std::cout << j << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say C++ has nothing.  See [CppIterTools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools).

Answer (score 3):

Try using ranges instead of iterators. E.g. using Eric Niebler's [**range-v3**](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/test/view/concat.cpp) library, you can write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace ranges;

    std::vector<std::string> his_face{"this", "is", "his", "face"};
    std::vector<std::string> another_mess{"another", "fine", "mess"};
    std::cout << view::concat(his_face, another_mess);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac37c7ecab610218). Using Boost.Range, a [**similar result**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152216/boost-range-library-traversing-two-ranges-sequentially) can be obtained, but it's not as clean as using range-v3.